# service discovery during "Add Service Reference"

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

i'm building an Asp.Net app (contains the service) with Silverlight control (need to use the service) and having a problem after i discover the service and press OK button, can anyone help me please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try to rebuild both projects.Same issue..http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightstart/thread/c7704abf-c51b-401d-94d0-2787f84ccb90/

Comment: Thank you very much somehow helped i modified the web config and service config and worked

Comment: check service Metadata. Can you access yourURL?wsdl

Comment: Your Welcome  @Maged Nabil

Answer (score 0):

Try/Check the following:

- Your service project is being properly build with no errors.
- There is no other IIS / IIS express servers running in background.
- Try to open the service address that you are trying to consume in the browser and see if it is loaded OK.

This should give you a lead on the problem.